# How to make a command repeat itself inside a python script at certain intervals

Tags: python

Looked at all the similar questions but unable to get the syntax correct. I have a python script that runs a single command at the moment. What I need to do is have this command repeat itself over and over...indefinitely...at certain intervals. Here is my script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP,UDP,send,DNS,DNSQR

p=send(IP(dst="192.168.1.128")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="domain.com")), count=100 )
if p:
p.show()
```

This runs fine from the command line. However I need it to repeat every 30 seconds or 1 minute. How would I tell it to do that inside the script? I know I can probably set this up as a cron job but I'd like to know how to script it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `time` module's [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) method inside a `while True` loop.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP,UDP,send,DNS,DNSQR

while True:
    p=send(IP(dst="192.168.1.128")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="domain.com")), count=100)
    if p:
        p.show()
    time.sleep(60) # sleep for one minute
```

Comment: Probably the simplest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can put a infinite while loop and add sleep of 30 seconds in every iteration. The other option could be set the script into cron job.

The advisable option is cronjob as in case python script exit due to any exception or error, cron can re-run it in next cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Create a while loop. True is always True, so the loop keeps running. After the commands wait a while.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, time
interval = 60 #1 minute
from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP,UDP,send,DNS,DNSQR

while True:
    p=send(IP(dst="192.168.1.128")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="domain.com")), count=100 )
    if p:
        p.show()
    time.sleep(interval)
```

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop with the sleep as mentioned in the above answers is the simplest way to do what you want. However, if you do that, your program becomes a daemon which you have to monitor and make sure is running. This has some costs that you should be aware of up front.

I would prefer to use `cron` to run it every `n` minutes or something similar. Yet another way, which is similar to the inifinite loop is to the use the python [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module to run a mini cron like system inside your program.

Comment: I will look into that. Can you edit your answer to provide an example of what that would look like?